# Fatal error: Uncaught Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm getting this error in a simple login i'm developing:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_array() in D:\xampp\htdocs\script\login.php:18 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\script\login.php on line 18

So, this is my login.php:

```
<?php
require "banco.php";
session_start();
$login = isset($_POST["login"]) ? addslashes(trim($_POST["login"])) : FALSE;
$senha = isset($_POST["senha"]) ? md5(trim($_POST["senha"])) : FALSE;
if(!$login || !$senha){
    echo "Você deve digitar sua senha e login!";
    exit;}
$SQL = "SELECT id, nome, login, senha FROM usuario WHERE login = '$login' ";
$result_id = $db->query($SQL);// or die("Erro no banco de dados!");
$total = $result_id->fetchColumn();
if($total){
    $dados = @mysql_fetch_array($result_id);
if(!strcmp($senha, $dados["senha"])){
    $_SESSION["id_usuario"]= $dados["id"];
    $_SESSION["nome_usuario"] = stripslashes($dados["nome"]);
    header("Location: index.php");
exit;}
else{
    echo "Senha inválida!";
exit;}
```

How can i fix this? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Are you using PHP7? mysql has been removed in PHP7 in favor of MySQLi

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) for how to use PDO

Comment: check this http://www.sathyabaman.com/2016/05/16/pdo-database-insert-script-php/

Comment: I don't know how to change that to PDO, can anyone change for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that `mysql_fetch_array` is not a [PDO method](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It comes from the deprecated [`mysql_*` API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php).